# Bug in triangle verifier code for Python

Tags: python, geometry, conditional-statements

```
a = raw_input('side 1 \n')
b = raw_input('side 2 \n')
c = raw_input('side 3 \n')

def triangle_check(x, y, z):
    if x > 0 and y > 0 and z > 0:
        if z > (x + y) or y > (x + z) or x > (y + z):
            print 'impossible'
        else:
            print 'possible'

triangle_check(a, b, c)
```

I am getting a semantic error (I think). Even if I type a valid triplet such as `3, 4, 5`, I get the `impossible` message. Can anybody spot my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string, you should convert them to integers first. Otherwise the condition:

`if x>0 and y>0 and z>0:` is always True.

All strings are greater than integers.

```
>>> "-1" > 0
True
>>> "" > 0
True
```

`z>(x+y)` : And here you're actually concatenating two strings first and then comparing it to other string z.

**Fix:** Apply `int()` to convert those strings into integers:

```
a = int(raw_input('side 1 \n'))
b = int(raw_input('side 2 \n'))
c = int(raw_input('side 3 \n'))
```

Now it works fine.

Demo:

```
$ python so.py
side 1 
3
side 2 
4
side 3 
5
possible
```

Comment: Thanks! My system refreshed a little late and i didnt see your answer. So sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = raw_input('side 1 \n')
b = raw_input('side 2 \n')
c = raw_input('side 3 \n')

def triangle_check(x, y, z):
    if x > 0 and y > 0 and z > 0:
        if z > (x + y) or y > (x + z) or x > (y + z):
            print 'impossible'
        else:
            print 'possible'

triangle_check(int(a), int(b), int(c))
```

Need to convert `raw_input` to `int` as `raw_input` returns a `string`.